# XMLHttpRequest unexpectedly returns a communications error

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am new to PHP and am having difficulties with a piece of code. I am using an example, from *Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript*. The intent is to display a webpage, retrieved from the web using PHP, in a <div>>. Rather than displaying the google.com main webpage, I obtain "Communications error: status: 500 Internal Server Error". Can anyone advise me of what I am doing wrong.

The directory structure is:

```
amvetsfl292.org
  public_html
    PHP
```

The files contained in the PHP directory are:

```
Filename           Size   Description            Permission
async_request.js    478   JScript Script File    0644
test_php.html      1427   Firefox HTML Document  0644
url_post.php        408   PHP File               0644
```

I execute the test script from Firefox Developer with the address

```
amvetsfl292.org/PHP/test_php.html
```

I am not sure why the google home page is not displayed.

The source code files follow.

test_php.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>Asynchronous Communication Example</title>

  </head>

  <body style="text-align:center;">

    <h1>Loading a web page into a DIV</h1>
    <div id="info">This sentence will be replaced</div>

    <script src="async_request.js" ></script>

    <script>
      var params = "url=https://www.google.com";
      var request = new async_request ( );

      request.open ( "POST", "url_post.php", true );
      request.setRequestHeader ( 
                "Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

      request.onreadystatechange =
        function ( )
          {
          if ( this.readyState == 4 )
            {
            if ( this.status == 200 )
              {
              if ( this.responseText !== null )
                {
                document.getElementById ( "info" ).innerHTML =
                  this.responseText;
                }
              else 
                {
                alert ( "Communications error - No data received" );
                }
              }
            else 
              {
              alert ( "Communications error: " + 
                      "status: " + this.status +
                      " " + this.statusText );
              }
            }
          };

      request.send ( params );

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

async_request.js

```
/* jsl:option explicit */

function async_request ( )
  {
  try 
    {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest ( );
    }
  catch ( e1 )
    {
    try 
      {
      request = new ActiveXObject ( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" );
      }
    catch ( e2 )
      {
      try 
        {
        request = new ActiveXObject ( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
        }
      catch ( e3 )
        {
        return ( false );
        }
      }
    }

  return ( request );

  }
```

url_post.php

```
<?php // url_post.php

if ( isset ( $_POST [ "url" ] ) )
  {
  echo file_get_contents ( "https://" . 
                           sanitize_string ( $_POST [ "url" ] ) )
  }


function sanitize_string ( $var ) 
  {

  if ( get_magic_quotes_GPC ( ) )
    {
    $var = stripslashes ( $var );
    }
  $var = strip_tags ( $var );
  $var = htmlentities ( $var );
  return ( $var );
  }

?>
```

Comment: i not 100% certain but i think its something to do with CORS policy, basically what you are doing is exactly what phishing websites do so in order to prevent that google blocks itself from loading in another page

Comment: That error seems to be your custom error message for when the response is anything other than 200. Check if the response contains a real error message. You can also check your webservers error log to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: _Side note:_ I don't see the purpose of passing the URL through the `sanitize_string()` function? That function seems about preventing XSS, which isn't really an issue in this context. Strings should be sanitized differently depending how they are going to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url_post.php line 6 is missing a ';'

Comment: Thank you. I repaired the missing semicolon. The code ran but responseText was empty. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After I added the missing semicolon, the code ran differently but still with an error. In the error log I found that the software was trying to access the site htpps://https://www.google.com which of course does not exist. I changed the params variable from

```
  var params = "url=https://www.google.com";
```

to

```
  var params = "url=www.google.com";
```

Not only did the error go away, but the google home page appeared. Lesson - be wary of examples in books.

Thanks to every one for the thoughts.